# How to evaluate problems in the <head> of a Magento-project

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have problems with the setting of setRobots() in Magento 1.7.0.2 as I do set those in the backend via the XML-Update AND via the local.xml and though my cms-pages don't get the correct robots-tags. (the same btw also for description or other tags in the head-section)

I do know how to debug the visible parts of the frontend by activating the show-blocks in magentos' backend. But for the head-section that practice doesn't guide me no where. What starting point would be generally recommended to evaluate problems in that section?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like often, maybe a cache problem. config data is stored in cache and block rendering too.

Then you can edit the template at `app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/page/html/head.phtml` and/or the block linked `app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Head.php`

Check the `Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head::getRobots()` method